# Processor upgrade on a laptop vs. Ram upgrade. Also does ram always matter?

Tags: memory, performance, cpu, upgrade

I have a Dell Inspiron 14r (N4110) with an Intel Core i3 and 4gb of ram. It runs very smoothly, however gaming on this laptop is very limited. This is mostly because of integrated graphics but i have seen a computer with a Core i5, and very similar specs otherwise, run games that the N4110 cannot. This other computer has integrated graphics and 6gb of ram.

I am wondering whether upgrading ram or upgrading the processor make the most difference in performance. Which setup would get better performance, an i5 with 4gb of ram or an i3 with 8 gb of ram? (Both with integrated graphics)

Also, is there a certain point at which you have too much ram for the computer to ever possibly use? For instance is there really any difference in performance between 8 gb and 16 gb of ram?

Comment: I assume you use windows, but is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: You cannot upgrade a CPU in a laptop, at least easily. Also, if you have a 32 bit OS, upgrading your RAM would be pointless.

Comment: I have 64 bit Windows 7. I understand that a laptop upgrade in a laptop is rare, but the question is theoretical. Which setup would run better if you could replace the processor?

Comment: @Evan i5 has more cache-memory(6MB) than i3(3MB), integrated grahics is better than i3, if more ram, then i3 has to send instructions to fetch and search for whole 8GB.. upgrading RAM won't give performance. trust me.[see here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2416592,00.asp) and also [see this comparision](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-vs-Intel-Core-i3-3110M)

Comment: @cfinley I have 32bit OS and 8GB

Comment: You're asking us to compare processors without telling us which processors are being compared. The computer you saw with "a Core i5" could have had any of a large variety of processors with vastly different performances and even different generations of integrated video.

Comment: Even a child inside a mother's womb know that CPU decides the performance.. RAM-supporters are deceiving the question owner of this post. CAN ANYONE PROVE UPGRADING RAM OVER CPU GIVES PERFORMANCE? NEVER. Integrated graphics is inside CPU and has its own memory inside CPU THEN WHY NEED FOR MORE RAM????. THIS POST NEEDS MODERATOR ATTENTION.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the i3 is a dual core sandy bridge as is the i5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, your OS is 64bit, then why not opt for a dual chanel RAM configuration, having two similar RAM sticks installed. For integrated graphics, that seems to be the best option to increase performance, even if the increase is of about 10-20%

Comment: So you are saying the ram upgrade would give the best performance?

Comment: Actually, it serves as the only possible  possible alternative, you cannot easily upgrade the processor, and if it is soldered, you cannot upgrade it at all.

Comment: Yes, that's true but will it really increase my performance much?

Comment: @Evan That is actually a difficult question to answer, but from my experience, it does increase the performance. Can you tell me the generation of your processor?

Comment: My processor is Sandy Bridge.

Comment: From the profile of HD graphics 3000, let me be blunt, a 2x4 Gb configuration, might, I said might help you to increase framerates by 10% top, and that too for games whichever are running okay on it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more thing, could I possibly run DayZ if  I upgraded my ram?

Comment: Minimum requirements to run DayZ includes Intel HD Graphics 4000 , and Intel HD graphics 3000 is architecturally different, so 99%, the laptop might not be able to run it even after RAM upgrade

Comment: @Evan i5 has more cache-memory(6MB) than i3(3MB), integrated grahics is better than i3, if more ram, then i3 has to send instructions to fetch and search for whole 8GB.. upgrading RAM won't give performance. trust me. Integrated graphics deal with CPU. i5 has much better graphics to run huge games [see here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2416592,00.asp) and also [see this comparision](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-vs-Intel-Core-i3-3110M)